# Response.Redirect after thread finished?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want these actions on an aspx/aspx.vb page:

1. User clicks "Process" button
2. A background thread is started adding between 1000 and 100,000 records to an SQL database. This may take between 1 second and 20 seconds
3. When the background thread is finished, I want to Response.Redirect the user to another page
4. If the user accidentally navigates somewhere else or closes the browser window while the thread is still working, I want the thread to still keep working until completed.

What's the best/easiest way to do this? I've been reading posts about RunWorkerCompleted but that seems to be an old method or one only applicable to windows forms and not ASP.NET.

Comment: if you want the main request to wait, then what's the need for a background thread? You could just run it all on the main thread, surely? Just make sure there's sufficient timeout on the asp.net settings to allow it to complete even if it overruns.

Comment: But maybe a better architecture would actually be to trigger the job via something like websockets, so the job can genuinely run in the background without worries about timers or anything, you can then notify the page in real-time when it's complete and the client-side code can handle any redirect.

Comment: @ADyson In case the user decides to close the webpage after 10 seconds and then the main thread job which would have otherwise taken 20 seconds aborts, and the table insert only inserts 50,000 rows instead of 100,000 rows.

Comment: execute a console application on Process button.

Comment: @Atk Thanks but it’s on a Godaddy Shared Hosting account.

Comment: you could consider something like Hangfire, as well. But really this is a job for a separate background service, ideally. If you're on a shared hosting account which doesn't allow you to run scheduled tasks or Cron jobs, then you maybe need to consider moving hosts. Either that or you could put a limit on the number of rows which can be inserted each time, and force the user to batch them by repeatedly requesting to load them until it's finished. Not ideal, but works around the problem.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks. I've been trying to find out what code I would need to use a .Net Thread Delegate. It seems that could be used.